# Rationale behind introducing protected access specifier

Tags: c++

What was the rationale behind introducing protected access specifier in C++. An example would be helpful.

Comment: The rationale seems to have been "we need to do something to make the language more complicated than it needs to be and more fragile than it should be so that consultants can charge huge fees for bad work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `protected` access level is used when classes need to work together with their inheritors.

For example, imagine an abstract `Shape` class that can report its area to the outside world.

Different shapes, such as triangles, squares, and circles, are described differently (angle, side, radius) and calculate their areas differently.

The `Shape` class might have a public `getArea()` method that returns a private variable holding the area.
The best way to set this variable would be a `protected` method called `setArea(double)` which would be called by the child classes.

Thus, `Circle` would call `setArea(PI * radius * radius)`, `Square` would call `setArea(side * side)`, etc.

*Note that this is not necessarily a good design* (but it's a great example of `protected`)

Comment: The best way would probably to use a virtual `getArea` method.

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes, but that would mean recalculating the area every time it's called.

Comment: Not necessarily, it's up to the derived form to decide whether or not it's worth caching the result.

Answer (score 3):

For these kind of questions, I recommend *The Design And Evolution of C++* by Bjarne Stroustrup. Section 13.9 describes the evolution of protected members.

> Shortly after Release 1.0 [of Cfront], Mark Linton stopped by my office and made an impassioned plea for a third level of access control [...] He argued persuasively based on genuine experience and examples from real code that protected data was essential for the design of an efficient and extensible X windows toolkit. [...] These were good arguments and essentially the ones that convinced me to allow protected members. [...]
>
> Five years or so later, Mark banned the use of protected data members in *Interviews* [*the X windows toolkit mentioned earlier*] because they had become a source of bugs. [...] They also seriously complicate maintenance [...]
>
> Protected members were introduced into Release 1.2. Protected base classes were first described in Release 2.1. In retrospect, I think that `protected` is a case where "good arguments" and fashion overcame my better judgement and my rules of thumb for accepting new features.

Comment: I could not agree more, protected data members are a breach of encapsulation. I only use protected for methods.

Comment: @Matt: In my opinion, fields in classes should always implicitly be private with no mechanisms to prevent that, since both public and protected fields break encapsulation.

Comment: I have the very same opinion here. You can't enforce a class invariant if you expose your data members.

Comment: That assumes you have them. `class Color { public: unsigned char r,g,b; }` does not.

Comment: @MSalters: Then maybe it would make sense to make a very clean distinction between `struct` and `class` (as opposed to what C++ does).